# Compute Engine reverts firewall http/https rules automatically

Tags: google-compute-engine

I set the http/https rules through the UI on my VM, 
everything looks fine for roughly 2 hours, and then automatically I found them deactivated.

Any idea why this happens, and how can I avoid it? (ie.: cron job from the VM to reset the rules)

Comment: Are you referring to the instance's firewall rules, or the [firewall rules for the GCE VPC network](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls)?

Comment: Are you using your employers corporate GCP accounts?  If so, they may have scanners that examine projects to examine rules and apply remediation to GCP firewall rules to remove rules that conflict with business policies.  There may also be value in switching on appropriate audit log features such that you can capture changes of rules which might give you further info into who/what/why rules were changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To determine the source of the disabling of your firewall rules, I would suggest checking the [logs](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/overview) of your firewall rule using the advanced query below.

```
resource.type="gce_firewall_rule"
resource.labels.firewall_rule_id="[FIREWALL_ID]"
```

If your issue is that the network tags have been removed from your instance, I would suggest checking the logs of your instance using the advanced query below, to determine the source of the issue.

```
resource.type="gce_instance"
resource.labels.instance_id="[INSTANCE_ID]"
logName=("projects/[PROJECT_ID]/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Factivity" OR "projects/PROJECT_ID/logs/compute.googleapis.com%2Factivity_log")
```